# Use JavaScript with WTForms

Tags: javascript, python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I've been trying to use JavaScript to validate only numbers in a field.
But isn't working

Here I have the JavaScript code:

```
 <script language="JavaScript">
function onlyNumbers(evt)
{
var e = event || evt; // for trans-browser compatibility
var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;

if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;

return true;

}
</script>
```

and here I have the WTForms that I am using with Flask:

```
{{ form.saturacion.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                     {% if form.saturacion.errors %}
                        {{ form.saturacion(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  {% for error in form.saturacion.errors %}
                        <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.saturacion(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
```

These two are in the html file

And here I have the form:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField, SelectField,RadioField,IntegerField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired,Length, Email, EqualTo,ValidationError,InputRequired
from init.models import User

class PredictionForm(FlaskForm):
    saturacion = IntegerField('Saturacion de O2', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=1, max=2)])
```

Could someone please tell me how to allow only numbers in that field with WTForms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wtforms native `IntegerField` (imported with `from wtforms import IntegerField`) renders a text input:

```
class IntegerField(Field):
    """
    A text field, except all input is coerced to an integer.  Erroneous input
    is ignored and will not be accepted as a value.
    """
    widget = widgets.TextInput()
```

If you import the native HTML5 input (`from wtforms.fields.html5 import IntegerField`) then the validation is performed by your browser without the need for JS since the form input is of a different type:

```
class IntegerField(core.IntegerField):
    """
    Represents an ``<input type="number">``.
    """
    widget = widgets.NumberInput(step='1')
```

From reading your JS I can't see anywhere where you hook into the form submission process to prevent it or pass it through, and also I can't see how you are hooking your function to the specific form input.

Comment: Thank so much! It worked perfectly! Do you think that using  NumberRange(min=0, max=100) is a  good idea to control the range of numbers of the input?

Comment: The basic principle of web design form input validation is that you do it both on server side **and** on client side. If you want to restrict your users to only integers between 0 and 100 then apply that validator rule in your python code and also add it as an option on the HTML5 input form, which does permit this simple min-max validation. That way you are covered for both cases.